# Is it possible to transfer absolutely the entire balance of the Solana wallet?

Tags: lamports, burn, fee

Not SPL token.
For example:

1. Create a new Solana address
2. Transfer 1 SOL from my other wallet to this address
3. Return the entire amount received back to my main wallet (minus two transfer fees of 0.000005 SOL)

After that, the amount of 0.00203928 SOL remains on this new wallet.

In the case of an SPL token, I can simply close the token account and return this amount to the balance.
But how to collect this amount for SOL? How can I make the new wallet have a 0 SOL balance again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create connection

```
import { 
    clusterApiUrl, 
    Connection, 
    Transaction,  
    sendAndConfirmTransaction, 
    SystemProgram 
} from '@solana/web3.js';

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
```

get the balance of the pubKey

```
const balance = await connection.getBalance(pubKey);
```

Before transferring, you need to write an instruction:

```
const instruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: pubKey,
  toPubkey: toAddressHere,
  lamports: balance,
});
```

create the transaction

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);
```

you need the signers:

```
const signers = [
  {
    publicKey: pubKey,
    secretKey: walletSecretKeyHere,
  },
];
```

now execute the transaction

```
// return value is Promise<TransactionSignature>
// that is why call inside async function with await
const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  signers
);
```

Comment: Don't we need to account for transaction fees? When I try this, it fails with `custom program error: 0x1`

Comment: This would simply result in error as we are trying to transfer the entire balance but the gas fee will be deducted before the transaction is initiated thus resulting in less SOL being present in the account than required